# AdMob how to remove a showing ad?

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm developing a java android app that will contain a google admob banner ad at the bottom of the screen.

I have developed all the code and the ads are already working... but I want to implement a feature that will allow the user to remove the ads... imagine something like a internal not monetary purchase.

My question is: **How do I remove the ad that is currently showing in my activity without violating any AdMob rule?**

When the user starts an activity I simply dont initialize the ad, but if the ad is already showing how can I disabled it? I didn't find any official document about it, I just found some forums saying that setting the visibility to gone violates the rules...

Thanks!

Comment: With Banner Ad you can remove directly the AdView from the container to remove it and don't forget call the AdView.destroy() to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Can show the Close(X) icon on the top-right corner of the Banner Ad container, Destroy and Remove an adView from the Ad container while clicking on the Close icon.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the below code with your logic by setting the visibility
> to "INVISIBLE," you hide the ad, but it can still request and load
> ads, which can be useful if the user decides to re-enable ads later.
> If you remove the AdView entirely, you'll need to re-add it to the
> layout when the user wants to see ads again.

```
AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

// To hide the ad without violating AdMob policies
adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
// or
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Use this option with caution

// To remove the ad completely
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
if (parentView != null) {
    parentView.removeView(adView);
}
```